# How to send json data to jade from node.js?

Tags: node.js, pug

i have really important question about jade and node.js usage. i have a userlist function in node.js. i wanna  show my json data in side of node.js as jade page. but it will be empty.

i have 2 file: USERLIST.jade and index.js

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


/* GET Userlist page. */
router.get('/userlist', function (req, res) {
    var json = { name: "yusuf karatoprak", age: 42 };
    res.render('userlist', { userlist : json });

});


module.exports = router;
```

USERLIST.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        User List
    ul
        each user, i in userlist
            li

              #{user.name}
```

but it creates empty page. i can not see my json data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        User List
    ul
        li= userlist.name
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a JavaScript object, not an array. You don't need to loop it.

Either change your data to:

```
var json = [{ name: "yusuf karatoprak", age: 42 }];
```

Or change your view to:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        User List
    ul
        li
            #{userlist.name}
```

Answer (score -1):

This must work-

```
extends layout    
block content    
    h1.    
        User List    
    ul    
        each user, i in userlist    
            li #{user}
```