# How to create invoice template(of what they ordered) using HTML/JADE and send it to user/customer in nodejs and expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I need to send the customer a mail consisting of items he ordered. So I need to create a table in the template and it should iterate based on the length of the array of orderitems dynamically. I tried to use `javascript` in `HTML` but I'm not getting it. I tried `JADE` too, but I don't know how to fetch the data from controller to the `.jade` file. Is it possible with `HTML/JADE`? Or any other solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which database are you using. If you are using MongoDB, then you will get all the data objects in JSON format. Once the data is available, you can populate it in your Jade templates. The Jade templates should be under Views and I assume you have done proper routing to the template.

Comment: Yes, I'm using mongodb. I have used these two lines in my controller `var fn = jade.compileFile('./order.jade', {doctype: 'html'});`
`var html = fn(locals);` I'm getting error like "Referenceerror: locals is not defined".

Comment: If you are using a controller and views, then i suppose you are using a framework like Express. Secondly, for the OrderItems you want to mail as invoice or display it first to the customer before mailing, there needs to be some routing. Even if you do not show it to the customer, there will be some kind of redirect or background processing. In the main controller perhaps (app.js) or (server.js), you can route these url’s. For example, a route can be like app.get(‘/oredr-list’, routes.customer.order-list);

Comment: Here routes is the folder and customer.js is a route file and oredr-list is the method that you export. It may vary in your case. For example, you may altogether remove the customer file, so it will become, something like app.get(‘/order-list’,routes.order-list). So, whenever user goes to the url yoursite.com:xxxx/oredr-list the method/ function order-list will be executed. In this order-list you write your function for retrieving the data and then render it to the jade template. Now refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966173/how-to-send-json-data-to-jade-from-node-js